# JSP Processing instruction not closed

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, include, jspinclude

I tried to include an HTML file to my JSP but I eclipse show'd this error

The included file

```
<%@include file="includes/head.html" %>
```

And the error

```
Processing instruction not closed
```

And this is just the simple JSP

```
<%@include file = "includes/head.html" %>

    <form action = "#" method = "POST">
        Username: <input type = "text" name = "username"><br/>
        Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"><br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wild guess: all the code examples I can find have a space between the `@` and the `include`, try adding one? Also, does the error go away when you remove the whole directive? (To make sure that's where the problem is.) It's also possible the error is actually in the included file.

Comment: Ignore the IDE error message and try to run it.

Comment: Could you please provide head.html file because this will run file may problem with head.html. Error shows that "Not able to parse file"

Comment: Post your `head.html` here.  It seems that you've missed any `closing tag` in `head.html`.

Comment: along with the comment by @subodh I have found that sometimes Eclipse (if you are using it) get's believes an error is created while you are typing in a legitimate include/link (css)/or script file tag.  I have had luck closing and reopening Eclipse.

Answer (score 65):

Select All, Backspace,Then ctrl+z to revert. works for me. But someone who knows eclipse well might shed some light as to why this happens

Comment: damn! it worked like charm. Could it be a bug in Eclipse Editor ?
This happens a lot of time with me. The code is correct but still I'm left wondering about my opening and closing tags. This annoying thing just wastes my time unnecessarily.

Comment: Damn!, wasted more time, your post helped me  a lot

Comment: WOW!! it worked!! I don't know how and why. Thanks!! :D

Comment: Half an hour searching for the mistake, read and try this. All solved. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 11):

This seems crazy but press ctrl + A,ctrl + x,paste and save the code,Bug is cleared

Answer (score 3):

Also, closing the document and opening it again appears to work (please remember to save the document first).

Answer (score 1):

i try Anurag Priyadarshi answer but it didnt work. But i get rid of that error by restart the eclipse, u might wanna try it it works for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Save same code in new file by deleting the error file does worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a space after @.

```
<%@ include file="includes/head.html" %>.
```

Also if head.html is in other directory then absolute path should start with / or ..
Try
`<%@ include file="/includes/head.html" %>` or

```
<%@ include file="../includes/head.html" %>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting eclipse worked for me.