# Eclipse java tags visible in html output window

Tags: java, eclipse, output, eclipse-luna

I'm using Eclipse(Luna) Windows, mysql database connector/j and a mysql database on wamp. My small program connects ok to the database but when I run my data.jsp(html) file to the output window I get all the tags. [I've replicated the problem below simply]

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %><%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.*" %><?xml version="1.0"?>
<tours>
<%
    out.println("Hello World");
%>
</tours>
```

I fixed the first bug when the `<?xml...?>` tag was red-lined with Anurag Priyadarshi's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17562015/2444916

but the output was the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<tours>Hello World</tours>
```

...Image available at matzdevworld.com/art/screendump_03.jpg

There are no red errors in the eclipse interface! Why are the tags visible??

Comment: Output Window Means Browser? or We Page editor?

Comment: How exactly are you "running" the file?

Comment: ...Inside Eclipse with the integrated web browser. I'm doing the training course through Lynda video training and it's a little bit annoying that they are not getting the same error/red-line message as me!

Comment: I can't add images yet! tsk!!!  ...Image available at matzdevworld.com/art/screendump_03.jpg

Comment: Well, you're sending XML, and not HTML. How do you expect the browser to render that XML?

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

...should be...

```
<? xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Just another Eclipse bug, thanks for all your help.